# How to modify grepped output with cut or awk in Unix?

Tags: unix, grep

I have a grepped output that I desire, however I would like to modify it a bit further to get the necessary results but quite uncertain how to do so. Unix Cut or awk?

Example of the grepped output:

```
Receivedrequest[Sai, Year=2023, Birth=1999, Location=SYD]
```

Desired Output:

```
Sai 2023 199 SYD
```

tried this but doesn't give me the desired output

```
grep -I '15:00.*Receivedrequest.*' test.log | awk '{print $2,$3,$4}' | cut -d "[" -f2
```

output

```
Sai, 2023, Birth=1999
```

Comment: [There](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) you will find information on how to format your question with Markdown.

Comment: Is `199` a typo?

Comment: You don't need grep if you're using awk. Post a [mcve] including your original input and final desired output so we can help you.

Answer (score 2):

Based on given sample, here are solutions using `sed` and `awk` (they both support filtering, so no need `grep`):

```bash
$ sed -nE '/Receivedrequest/s/[^[]+\[([^,]+),[^=]+=([^,]+),[^=]+=([^,]+),[^=]+=([^]]+).+/\1 \2 \3 \4/p' test.log
Sai 2023 1999 SYD

$ awk -F'[][,=]' '/Receivedrequest/{print $2, $4, $6, $8}' test.log
Sai 2023 1999 SYD
```

Answer (score 0):

```
echo 'Receivedrequest[Sai, Year=2023, Birth=1999, Location=SYD]' |
```

---

```
   mawk NF-- FS='.+[[]|,[^=]*.|.$' # leading edge 1 extra space
    
    Sai 2023 1999 SYD
   %
```

---

```
  gawk 'sub(".",_,$!--NF)' FS='.+[[]|,[^=]*.|.$' #no extra space

  Sai 2023 1999 SYD
  %
```

Answer (score 0):

Using AWK

- Using `[` & `]` as delimiter `-F'[][]'`
- Looking for string Receivedrequest `/Receivedrequest/`
- Replacing any from `,` to `=` with blank `gsub(/,[^=]*=/," ")`
- Printing second field `print $2`

```
$ awk -F'[][]' '/Receivedrequest/{gsub(/,[^=]*=/," "); print $2}' test.log 
Sai 2023 1999 SYD
```

Comment: Could you please explain your answer a bit more to understand your way?

Comment: FYI that'll behave the same way in any awk, it doesn't require GNU awk.